# (mysql_real_query) breaks while inserting some records

Tags: c, mysql

I am writing a c application that works with mysql database. the best mysql function to insert record to database I know is "`mysql_real_query`" Most of my insert queries contain mixed data captured from network flow. for some queries, the execution breaks saying..

```
mysql_real_query error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

What are other possible ways I can parse these data to mysql table without breaking.?

Comment: Belongs on Stack Overflow. You should add an example of the query you use, this looks like you simply have and error in your SQL and then it won't work with whatever method you use.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of errors are very annoying when using mysql connectors in c. I had the same problem as you describe.

So, the solution for me was the `MySQL DB Pool` system, which allows you to lock connections with mysql and prevent this kind of execution breaks.

If you combine DB Pool with strong checks when building the queries, you'll overtake this kind of issues.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of [DBPoolMySQL](https://github.com/dimimpou/DBPoolMySQL), feel free to use it, join or contribute to improve it. Of course you can try [Libzdb](http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/), which its an option, but its not really clear and customizable.